# Latex hanging when accessing data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I have the following code which generates a picture using the `tikz` package using an array of numbers. If I change the line:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\reds[\index]}
```

to access the larger array:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\REDS[\index]}
```

the build process just hangs. What am I doing wrong ?

```
\def\res{32}
\def\scale{0.22}

\def\reds
{{
1.00, 0.00, 1.00
}}

\def\REDS
{{
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00
}}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \mbox{} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \x in {1,...,\res}{
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\res}{

            \pgfmathparse{(\x-0.5)*\scale-\scale}\edef\blx{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathparse{(\y-0.5)*\scale-\scale}\edef\bly{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathparse{(\x-0.5)*\scale}\edef\trx{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathparse{(\y-0.5)*\scale}\edef\try{\pgfmathresult}

            \pgfmathparse{mod(((\x-1)*\res + \y-1),3)}\edef\index{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\reds[\index]}

            \definecolor{col}{rgb}{\r,0.7,0.4}

            \fill[col] (\blx,\bly) rectangle (\trx,\try);
        }
    }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Did you wait enough ? It is reaaaally slow as it emulates an array but basically a text based parser.

Comment: I left it running for over an hour. Surely it would not take longer than that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wait enough this leads to a result. But I don't know why you are looking up a value which is between 0 and 2 from an array that is 32x32.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\res{32}
\def\scale{0.22}
\def\reds{{1.00, 0.00, 1.00}}
\def\REDS
{{
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,
1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00,1.00, 0.00, 1.00
}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\res}{
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\res}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\blx}{(\x-0.5)*\scale-\scale}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\bly}{(\y-0.5)*\scale-\scale}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\trx}{(\x-0.5)*\scale}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\try}{(\y-0.5)*\scale}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\index{mod(((\x-1)*\res + \y-1),3)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\REDS[\index]}
            \definecolor{col}{rgb}{\r,0.7,0.4}
            \fill[col] (\blx,\bly) rectangle (\trx,\try);
        }
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got it in 0m58.667s

Comment: Never claimed the code was meaningful, just that it doesn't work. What governs the speed of execution ? Just the hardware spec or can I get a faster version of pdflatex et. al. ?

Comment: You replace array of 3 by array of 32x32 and the time (in my case) is multiplied "only" by 20 (=80s/4s). This means that extracting from array is not so slow ;) You should know that tex is not like standard programming language where accessing the n-th element of an array is super fast. Here you should parse the array before to extract the element. And, no, there is no faster pdflatex as far as I know, but you can check LuaLaTeX where you can use Lua for this.